# getJSON nao funciona

Tags: jquery

ele nao retorna o valor de sucesso, mas no erro ele diz que estava tudo certo

```
$.getJSON( "en-us.json", function( json ) {
  console.log( "SUCESS");
 }).fail(function(m) {
    console.log(m);
});
```

Imagem: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) o `jQuery.ajax` (e seus "primos") usam `Deferred` (assim como no seu código), no caso você não consegue enxergar o erro, pois você está pegando o `jqXHR` ao invés do `textStatus` ou `errorThrown`:

```
jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
```

Para usar no seu código faça isto:

```
$.getJSON( "en-us.json", function( json ) {
  console.log( "SUCESS");
 }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

### Possíveis causas do problema

- Se está usando um servidor como Apache (`http://localhost`) é possivel que o arquivo esteja em outra pasta e você tenha que corrigir o apontamento, por exemplo, se o `en-us.json` e o `jquery.js` estão na pasta `./js` mas o seu html está na pasta raiz, o jQuery vai procurar na pasta raiz ao invés da pasta `./js`, para corrigir aponte a pasta correta no `$.geJSON` (isto é apenas um exemplo):

  ```
  $.getJSON("js/en-us.json", function( json ) {
      console.log( "SUCESS");
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
  });
  ```
- Se não está usando um servidor pache (`http://localhost`) é provavel que esteja tentando acessar via [file URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme), note que o Ajax não trabalha com o protocolo 'file:///' por medidas de segurança dos browsers, para isto use um servidor HTTP local de sua preferencia.
- Se está usando HTTP o caminho está certo, então pode ser as permissões de pasta ou de extensões permitidas (como no caso dos servidores IIS), neste caso é necessário liberar a permissão da pasta (em sistemas like-unix por exemplo) ou configurar o IIS (se for o seu caso) para permitir mostrar arquivos com a extensão `.json`
- Se nenhum dos problemas acima é o seu, então podemos presumir que o seu servidor não está enviando o cabeçalho correto, que no caso deveria ser `Content-Type: application/json`, para isto é necessário configurar o seu servidor.

  - No Apache seria algo tipo:

    AddType application/json .json
  - No IIS é algo como:

    Abra o *IIS Manager*
    Visualize as propriedades do IIS Server
    Clique em `MIME Types` e em `Add`
    Adicione a extensão:

    - File name extension: `.json`
    - MIME type: `application/json`

    Volte para as proprieades do IIS Server
    Clique em `Handler Mappings`
    Adicione um `script map`

    - Request path: *.json
    - Executable: C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll
    - Name: JSON

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro parâmetro do `$.getJSON()`, [de acordo com a sua própria documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), deve ser uma URL. Isso acontece porque o método acessará o seu recurso via uma requisição HTTP utilizando o verbo GET.

Ao que tudo indica, `en-us.json` não está sendo encontrado. Você está tentando acessar um arquivo ou uma URL? Se for arquivo, a [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/) lhe será útil; do contrário, especifique uma URL válida.

Para dar mais propriedade a minha resposta, preparei um jsFiddle com um exemplo operando: confira-o [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/d2wpasm8/).

Answer (score 0):

Assim o `$.getJSON` funciona normalmente o que pode estar acontecendo e que a função não esta encontrado o arquivo ou ele esta em um formato invalido. Faz uma pesquisa sobre "formato de arquivo json" que tu vai encontrar como formatar certo um arquivo json, provavelmente seja isso.